# Custom Onlayout not working

Tags: android, viewgroup

Can anybody tell me how to change data dynamically in onLayout().i want to display first 8 values and after rotation complete another 8 values until it display array limit.here is my code-

```
if (position < conversion.length) {

                if (!childRotate) {
                    child.setAngle(angle);
                    child.setPosition(i);
                    position = i;
                    child.setImageResource(conversion[position]);
                    Float an = angle;
                    Log.i("prj,=angle", an.toString() + ",i=" + i.toString()
                            + ",onlayout,position=" + position.toString());
                    position++;

                } else {

                    child.setAngle(angle);
                    child.setPosition(i);
                    child.setImageResource(conversion[position]);
                    Float an = angle;
                    Log.i("prj,angle=", an.toString() + ",i=" + i.toString()
                            + ",onlayout,position=" + position.toString());
                    position++;
                    // childRotate = false;

                }
            }
            left = Math
                    .round((float) (((layoutWidth / 2) - childWidth / 2) + radius
                            * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle))));
            top = Math
                    .round((float) (((layoutHeight / 2) - childHeight / 2) + radius
                            * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))));

            child.layout(left, top, left + childWidth, top + childHeight);
            angle += angleDelay;
```